# Building a Progress Indicator in Rails for a Long Running (Open4) Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'll list this scenario out in bullet form to hopefully keep the description of the problem as simple as possible.

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- user submits a form, the record is saved and then a long-running forked process is triggered
- in the view, the user is redirected (to the show action), and the user should see a realtime progress indicator of said forked process.
- the forked process knows the record id and can instantiate it as the record has already been saved
- the record's model has an attr_accessor for 'status'
- the standard out of the forked process returns the completion percentage in whatever increments I choose

Problems:

- i cannot get the "self.status" or even an instantiated "@record.status" (defined in the open4 process) scoped to the record's (show) view
- On the "show" page that the user is redirected to, the "status" field value is not updated despite the forked process updating it (assuming this is because the value is only saved across requests)
- in trying to save to a session variable instead, apparently 'session' is not available to the forked process which is defined in the model (solutions to this seem really hacky).

Question:
What is the best way to address this problem?  I'm assuming implementing a progress indicator for a long running process is a pretty common task, I'm just not sure of the best way to implement it.  I have a few ideas using session[:status] and scoping it to the model, but I'd like to hear some better suggestions.  I'm also concerned about the possibility of many (100's?) of these processes running, is tracking their progress via session a good idea?  Maybe I should just move the code in question out of the model and somewhere 'session' is in scope?

Any ideas would be great. Fyi, on the front end I just plan to poll the 'status' object every 3 seconds or so from an ajax request. As a result, persisting the value in the DB would be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, u should write the precentage of process for your long time job to Rails cache, fro example, `Rail.cache.write("#{record_id}_status", 0.1)`, until the job is done, do `Rail.cache.write("#{record_id}_status", 1)`, you can control the precentage for your process,
then, in your show page, you known the record_id, use ajax poll the record_id 's status in Rails server `Rails.cache.read("#{record_id}_status")`, so it will known the precentage in your page

Comment: Ah, that should work well.  I don't have time to implement it tonight, but that should not have any of the scoping issues I'm having. I may use memcached instead just so I'm not writing these values to disk, but this approach should work.  Thanks!